# Proof or counterexample: If $F\subseteq K$ and $r\in K$. If $[F(r):F]=4$ then $F(r)=F(r^3)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, examples-counterexamples, extension-field

$F$ and $K$ are fields.

Proof or counterexample: If $F\subseteq K$ and $r\in K$. If $[F(r):F]=4$ then $F(r)=F(r^3)$.

I think I need to find a polynomial in $F(r^3)[x]$ that has $r$ as a root. I can't seem to figure that out though and how to prove it true if that were the case.

Similarly, I'm having issues with the same idea else where.

If $r^5 \in F$ but $r\notin F$ then $[F(r):F]=5$.

For this, I was thinking maybe it was false and I could come up with a counterexample.

If we let $r=\sqrt{5}^{1/5}$ and $r^5=5$. If we let our field be something like $a+b\sqrt{5}$ then $r$ and $r^5$ could both be in there and then we just need to make it such that our dimension is $4$ and we'd have a counterexample, no?

Any help would be great. I am having trouble understanding these types of problems.

Comment: Do you mean something like $[F(r):F]=[F(r):(r^3)]\cdot [F(r^3)]:F]$?

Comment: Thanks, that helped. If you wanted to write what you said up I can accept it.

Comment: I believe my comments may have been incorrect/misleading - my apologies. I've deleted them accordingly.

Comment: I hope so (not because I want you to be wrong of course!) because if you were both right somehow then I was really very lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is false.

Take $F=\mathbb Q$ the rationals, and $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{12}}$. $\omega$ is a primitive $12$-root of unity, and we know that in this case $[\mathbb Q(\omega):\mathbb Q]=\phi(12)=4$. (If you do not know what this means, search for Euler totient.). Now see $\omega^3=e^{\frac{3(2\pi i)}{12}}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{4}}$, so $[\mathbb Q(\omega^3):\mathbb Q]=\phi(4)=2$, and with this we conclude that the proposition is false.

Comment: It should be $x^6$ instead of $x^5$.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand the above.

Comment: Fixed proof. Thanks.

Comment: That was before, I edited it, and make it more simple.

Comment: Oh ok, I deleted my comment.

Comment: Can anyone explain this solution more thoroughly? I'm having a hard time understanding it and cannot determine if it is indeed correct.